# MATLAB: How to filter a signal using Thiran Fractional Delay Filter

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design

I have generated a Thrian fractional delay filter using (thiran function) in MATLAB

```
h=thiran(0.3,1)
```

where 0.3 is the time delay and 1 is the sample time. The output is a discrete time transfer function, the generated filter is all-pass, infinite impulse response (IIR) filter.

The problem is that I could not apply it to a signal `x(t)`. So I would like to know how to filter a signal with the generated thiran filter in MATLAB, what should I use to filter a signal with thiran filter? I can generate thiran filter using (thiran) function and the result will be a discrete time tf, but how to use it to filter a signal. I have tried to use `filter`, `conv` and `tf` functions but they all did not work:

`filter` and `conv` functions did not work because they require polynomial coefficients or numerator and denominator coefficients `b` and `a`, whereas `thiran` function generates a discrete transfer function.

```
[num,den] = tf(d)
```

function did not work because it can only convert a filter transfer function which is configured by `designfilt` function, so in this case `d` cannot be a thiran filter, `d` can only be configured by `designfilt` function

Comment: which command have you used to generate the filter? to which class does the output belong ? Without these informations it is difficult to help you. Please read [ask]

Comment: @Irreducible I have edited my question, it is much clearer now, thanks

Comment: you should type `whos h` and you would see that it is a `tf` class. You can also see this in your workspace. Googling: (how to apply a tf on time series?) gives you the idea to apply `lsim(h,x)` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

> ```
> h=thiran(0.3,1);
> num=  cell2mat(h.Numerator);
> denum=cell2mat(h.Denominator);
> output=filter(num,denum,x)
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks very much, that solved my problem, really helpful